# Can I use animated emoji?

Tags: web-app, crm, emoji

I am working on SASS based CRM system and I want to know if I can use emoji like Skype's emoji in my system.

I want to put it on the subscription expiration page.

Any suggestion apart from this?

Comment: Are you asking if you can as in 'technically is it possible?' or are you asking *should* you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Keep your audience in mind**

It might look unprofessional if you add emojis to the CRM system if it's built to serve to a group of professionals. You've not mentioned what emoji you are going to use on the subscription expiration page but I don't think there's need for an emoji.

**Try not to use emoji on the payment related pages**

It's better if you keep the page simple and to the point, and try to focus more on converting your customers to renew their subscriptions. Animated glyphs might often draw away the users attention unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you do a survey with potential customers and see if they fit their needs or adds additional values to your Software as a Service(SaaS) CRM application. As it is distributed to various kind of customers, their requirements can vary.

**If it's a need of your software itself then go ahead and implement it, but make it an on Demand Feature**. And finally, test, test, test.....